# Why does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{r^k(k+n)!}{k!}=\frac{n!}{(1-r)^{n+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

When I put the following series in Mathematica, I get an answer:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{r^k(k+n)!}{k!}=\frac{n!}{(1-r)^{n+1}}$$

Here $0<r<1$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer.

My question is: how does one arrive at this solution (without the use of Mathematica)?  I'd like to learn how to solve this by hand...  The $\frac{(k+n)!}{k!}$ looks like a Pochammer symbol $(k+1)^{(n)}$...

Comment: It should not be $r^m,$ right?

Comment: Oh yes of course.  Thanks for the catch.  I fixed the title also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{(k+n)!}{k!}=n!\cdot\dfrac{(k+n)!}{n!\cdot k!}=n!\cdot\Large{n+k\choose k}$. Now see [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases).

Comment: Oh, this is neat -- I did not see that!  Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Start with the geometric series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}\ ,$$
then differentiate $n$ times.